# CSS de Iframe otra pagina

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo un Iframe, en el cual muestro una pagina web (no tengo acceso al codigo fuente).

La pregunta es, hay forma de modificar el estilo de dicha pagina en el Iframe? O bien escalar o resaltar el tamaño de las letras, colores de dicha pagina? O que otro metodo pudiese usar para alterar el diseño de esta?

Leyendo preguntas relacionadas, puede prestarse a usurpación de la pagina, pero en este caso no es así la pagina esta dentro de la empresa y misma página se requiere tal como está actualmente y en un tercer monitor alterar el diseño de la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Si defines los estilos que quieres modificar en el formulario como variables de css, después puedes modificarlas desde el formulario padre de esta forma

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.querySelector('body').setAttribute('style', `--nombre-de-la-variable-css: nuevo-valor`);
```

Comment: Creo no me explique correctamente.

La pagina que mostrare en el iframe es ajena a mi, no tengo acceso al codigo de ella. Aun asi se puede hacer?